# Almacenar consulta Mysql en Array

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un código muy simple en donde hago una consulta y muestro el resultado en una lista, pero adicional a eso necesito que el dato de las carreras que se obtiene de la consulta se almacene en otra variable, en donde al llamarla y mostrarla en un campo del formulario, me muestre todas las carreras de la consulta. Hasta ahora solo logro cargar una sola carrera en la variable.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th>Carrera</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Rol</th>
            <th>Estado Usuario</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>

    $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT u.idusuario, u.nombre, u.correo, c.nombre_carr as 
    nombre_carrera, u.usuario
    FROM usuario u INNER JOIN carr c on u.id_carrera=c.id
    WHERE u.estatus = 1");

    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($result > 0)
    {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {       
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data["idusuario"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["nombre"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["correo"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["nombre_carrera"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["usuario"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está en el while, tu condición debería ser:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Para así recorrer a toda la array.